# Какой кодировщик кодирует до 3 символов?

Tags: c#, кодировка, хеширование

Нужен кодировщик, который кодирует цифры в 3 символа для создания уникального идентификатора человека. Конкуренты используют такие идентификаторы, поэтому я знаю что это возможно. Ближайшее что нашёл - CRC16, он кодирует в четыре символа, но нужен кодировщик именно в три и меньше.
Прикрепляю скрин, обратите внимание на 3-2 символа под именем на персонажах. Бывает один символ, два или три.
[image: Скрин]

Comment: В чем проблема запаковать полученный результат? Есть таблица символов, есть данные. Расставьте биты так, чтобы данные влезли в нужный диапазон значений, и готово. Примером может служить Base64, но у него результат длиннее в байтах, чем исходник, потому что у него всего 6 бит из 8 на байт. Вам надо наоборот, берите многбайтовую кодировку (например UTF-*) и экспериментируйте. Но это лишь мои догадки, до конца непонятно, что именно вам нужно.

Comment: Это називається хешированием, или же, подсчётом контрольной суммы. И такого не существует для 3 символов (длина, разрядность), размер всегда будет степенью двойки. И... CRC16 кодирует в два байта, то-есть два символа, не в 4. Но если вам надо меньше, есть CRC8 - 1 байт. Но будьте готовы к колизиям...

Comment: Кстати, если речь про 3 байта, то 2^24=16777216, то есть если сгенерировать это количество хэшей + 1 хэш, то как минимум 2 хэша будут равны между собой. Никакой магии, чистая математика.

Comment: `но нужен кодировщик именно в три и меньше` - так любой "неблочный" (потоковый) метод шифрования выдаёт на выходе шифр такой-же длины, что и на входе. Это может быть RC4 или AES в режиме GSM.

Comment: 3 символа?  может они просто кодируют номер человека в базе? тогда вполне реально. Правда нужно будет чуточку магии, что бы не получить номера "подряд". Может Вы покажите этих "конкурентов с их номерами"?

Comment: @KoVadim Спасибо за помощь, но пока-что всё не подходит. Я прикреплил скриншот с примером в пост, возможно он поможет понять что я хочу.

Comment: @PRODIGY Спасибо за помощь, но пока-что всё не подходит. Я прикреплил скриншот с примером в пост, возможно он поможет понять что я хочу.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за помощь, но пока-что всё не подходит. Я прикреплил скриншот с примером в пост, возможно он поможет понять что я хочу.

Comment: думаю, это просто номер человека (персонажа) в некой базе. просто записано в виде 36 ричной системы. Посмотрите на вот этот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625495/itoa-conversion-in-c-sharp . Да, при трех символах 0..9A..Z будет чуть больше 45тыс идентификаторов, но может этого хватит?

Comment: @KoVadim у них больше 100000 персонажей, возможно некоторые до 4 символов расширены. Но спасибо за ответ, сейчас изучу..

Comment: если используются только цифры и буквы (без регистра), то больше 36*36*36 = 46656 не взять никак. Но если использовать регистр, то это уже 52*52*52 = 140608.